# file's date changes after zip in and out again, according to XCOPY

Tags: windows, command-line, ntfs

So, here's the problem: I have files which are regular files, and they are put into a ZIP file (see below for details on ZIP). Then I unzip them (see below for details on the tool used), and the files are restored. The date of the file is restored, as in standard in the ZIP/UNZIP tools used. When querying using DIR, or in Windows Explorer, the files involved have the same date as they had, before being handled by the ZIP/UNZIP process.

So, all OK.

But then, I'm using the `XCOPY /D` command, to further manipulate different copies of those files on the disk ... and, XCOPY says : one file is newer than the other one. Given the fact the date, hour, up until minutes is the same .. the difference would be regarding a smaller entity, like seconds ?

All involved disks have NTFS file system.

Example:

```
C:\my>dir C:\windows\Background_mycomputer.cmd C:\my\directory\Background_mycomputer.cmd
 Volume in drive C is mycomputerC
 Volume Serial Number is 1234-5678

 Directory of C:\windows

31/12/2014  19:50                51 Background_mycomputer.cmd
               1 File(s)             51 bytes

 Directory of C:\my\directory

31/12/2014  19:50                51 Background_mycomputer.cmd
               1 File(s)             51 bytes
               0 Dir(s)  33.655.316.480 bytes free

C:\my>xcopy C:\windows\Background_mycomputer.cmd C:\my\directory\Background_mycomputer.cmd /D
Overwrite C:\my\directory\Background_mycomputer.cmd (Yes/No/All)? y
C:\windows\Background_mycomputer.cmd
1 File(s) copied

C:\my>xcopy C:\my\directory\Background_mycomputer.cmd C:\windows\Background_mycomputer.cmd /D
0 File(s) copied

C:\my>xcopy C:\windows\Background_mycomputer.cmd C:\my\directory\Background_mycomputer.cmd /D
0 File(s) copied

C:\my>unzip -v
UnZip 6.00 of 20 April 2009, by Info-ZIP.  Maintained by C. Spieler.  Send
bug reports using http://www.info-zip.org/zip-bug.html; see README for details.

Latest sources and executables are at ftp://ftp.info-zip.org/pub/infozip/ ;
see ftp://ftp.info-zip.org/pub/infozip/UnZip.html for other sites.

Compiled with Microsoft C 13.10 (Visual C++ 7.1) for
Windows 9x / Windows NT/2K/XP/2K3 (32-bit) on Apr 20 2009.

UnZip special compilation options:
        ASM_CRC
        COPYRIGHT_CLEAN (PKZIP 0.9x unreducing method not supported)
        NTSD_EAS
        SET_DIR_ATTRIB
        TIMESTAMP
        UNIXBACKUP
        USE_EF_UT_TIME
        USE_UNSHRINK (PKZIP/Zip 1.x unshrinking method supported)
        USE_DEFLATE64 (PKZIP 4.x Deflate64(tm) supported)
        UNICODE_SUPPORT [wide-chars] (handle UTF-8 paths)
        MBCS-support (multibyte character support, MB_CUR_MAX = 1)
        LARGE_FILE_SUPPORT (large files over 2 GiB supported)
        ZIP64_SUPPORT (archives using Zip64 for large files supported)
        USE_BZIP2 (PKZIP 4.6+, using bzip2 lib version 1.0.5, 10-Dec-2007)
        VMS_TEXT_CONV
        [decryption, version 2.11 of 05 Jan 2007]

UnZip and ZipInfo environment options:
           UNZIP:  [none]
        UNZIPOPT:  [none]
         ZIPINFO:  [none]
      ZIPINFOOPT:  [none]

C:\my>ver

Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601]

C:\my>zip -?
Copyright (c) 1990-2006 Info-ZIP - Type 'zip "-L"' for software license.
Zip 2.32 (June 19th 2006). Usage:
zip [-options] [-b path] [-t mmddyyyy] [-n suffixes] [zipfile list] [-xi list]
  The default action is to add or replace zipfile entries from list, which
  can include the special name - to compress standard input.
  If zipfile and list are omitted, zip compresses stdin to stdout.
  -f   freshen: only changed files  -u   update: only changed or new files
  -d   delete entries in zipfile    -m   move into zipfile (delete files)
  -r   recurse into directories     -j   junk (don't record) directory names
  -0   store only                   -l   convert LF to CR LF (-ll CR LF to LF)
  -1   compress faster              -9   compress better
  -q   quiet operation              -v   verbose operation/print version info
  -c   add one-line comments        -z   add zipfile comment
  -@   read names from stdin        -o   make zipfile as old as latest entry
  -x   exclude the following names  -i   include only the following names
  -F   fix zipfile (-FF try harder) -D   do not add directory entries
  -A   adjust self-extracting exe   -J   junk zipfile prefix (unzipsfx)
  -T   test zipfile integrity       -X   eXclude eXtra file attributes
  -!   use privileges (if granted) to obtain all aspects of WinNT security
  -R   PKZIP recursion (see manual)
  -$   include volume label         -S   include system and hidden files
  -e   encrypt                      -n   don't compress these suffixes

C:\my>
```

**Question: I do not want XCOPY to make updates where I know they are invalid cause the time format is doing something wrong. How do I prevent that ?**

From how I see, there's different things involved, being XCOPY, very specific ZIP and UNZIP, and NTFS file system. Which one is doing something wrong ?

I must stress that apart from ZIP and UNZIP, there are **no** other changes done to the file, like changing 1 file, then making a change to another one, in less than 60 seconds time.

At moment of test, the time shown was NOT the current time, and not close to it either. No file is adjusting to the current time, the times refer to last changes of the file in question, which may be any time in the past. In this case, it's one day later, but it can be anything.

Comment: "The FAT filesystem of DOS has a timestamp resolution of only two seconds; .ZIP file records mimic this. As a result, [the built-in timestamp resolution of files in a .ZIP archive is only two seconds](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zip_(file_format)#File_headers)."

Comment: By means of that, I understand that ZIP/UNZIP is not adapted enough to NTFS date/time precision ? So, if I would do the above on a FAT filesystem, there'll be no problem ? But what if I want to use NTFS ?

Comment: There is a zip extension for high precision timestamps, but I don't know the details. I think DotNetZip uses this extension by default.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed the peculiar behavior Raymond Chen describes when writing a Powershell script ([GitHub link](https://github.com/mossrich/PowershellRecipes/blob/master/ArchiveOldLogs.ps1)) to freshen a zip archive using the `System.IO.Compression` and `System.IO.Compression.FileSystem` libraries.

Interestingly, Zip archives can store multiple copies of the same file with identical metadata (name, relative path, modification dates). Extracting the second copy of the file will fail in Windows Explorer because the file already exists.

When trying to prevent re-zipping a file was already archived, I checked the relative path and date, and noticed that there was a discrepancy of up to two seconds in the LastWriteTime. This workaround compensates for the loss of precision:

```
    $AlreadyArchivedFile = ($WriteArchive.Entries | Where-Object {#zip will store multiple copies of the exact same file - prevent this by checking if already archived. 
      (($_.FullName -eq $RelativePath) -and ($_.Length -eq $File.Length) )  -and 
      ([math]::Abs(($_.LastWriteTime.UtcDateTime - $File.LastWriteTimeUtc).Seconds) -le 2) #ZipFileExtensions timestamps are only precise within 2 seconds. 
    })
```

Also, the IsDaylightSavingTime flag is not stored in the Zip archive. As a result I was surprised when extracted files became an hour newer than the original archived file. I tried this several times and saw the extracted file's timestamp incremented by an hour every time it was compressed and extracted.
Here's a very ugly workaround that decreases the archived file time by one hour to make the original source file and extracted file timestamps consistent:

```
        If($File.LastWriteTime.IsDaylightSavingTime() -and $ArchivedFile){#HACK: fix for buggy date - adds an hour inside archive when the zipped file was created during PDT (files created during PST are not affected).  
            $entry = $WriteArchive.GetEntry($RelativePath)    
            $entry.LastWriteTime = ($File.LastWriteTime.ToLocalTime() - (New-TimeSpan -Hours 1)) 
        }
```

There's probably a better way to handle this. Unfortunately I'm not aware of any way to store a Daylight Savings indicator for a file in a .Zip archive, and that information is lost.